# Is xylene an acid?

Tags: acid-base

What is the pH of xylene, and is it considered to be a corrosive substance?

Specifically I am interested in how xylene might interact with electrical conductors and components, which contain copper, aluminum, and steel as well as plastic.

I can't seem to find a pH reading online (checked Wolfram Alpha, Wikipedia, and SDS for xylene and ethylbenzene). The SDS I found did not contain the symbol for corrosive materials, but could it be even lightly corrosive?

Comment: Xylene is not acid and is likely to attack the insulation on electrical components, not the metal conductor.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I was so preoccupied with the conductor I didn't think about possible interactions with the insulator.